# I am using ios an I am getting error while installing angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when I am trying to install Angular CLI via `npm install –g @angular/cli` I am getting an error.
The command I executed
`users-MacBook-Pro-3:~ user$ npm install –g @angular/cli`

**Error**

> npm ERR! arg Argument starts with non-ascii dash, this is probably
>   invalid: [ '–g', '@angular/cli' ] npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm
>   ERR! Invalid tag name "–g": Tags may not have any characters that
>   encodeURIComponent encodes.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-05-17T18_15_24_137Z-debug.log
>   users-MacBook-Pro-3:~ user$

Comment: You should use a n dash instead of an m dash, i.e. - instead of –

Comment: i didn't get it , can you explore it more

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what do you mean by  n dash instead of an m dash

Comment: Look at the width of the 2 dashs: - and –. Only one of those is an ASCII character (the first one) so the second one won't work in your command. I'm guessing you copied that command off the internet somewhere. If you try manually typing it in instead, it should work

Comment: tanks it is solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one of those is an ASCII character (the first one) so the second one won't work in command.command was copied  off the internet somewhere. it worked by doing it manually